# Android: how to achieve fling similar to app icon removal from android homescreen?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, gesture-recognition

`GestureDetector` class don't have any implementation for dragging a `View`, while drag & drop don't support flinging.
So how does one implement detecting fling on a `View` and make the actual transition of the `View` from current position to target position?

Comment: see `OnGestureListener#onFling` and `OnGestureListener#onScroll` methods

Comment: also if you are using `support-v4` library, `android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper` could be helpful

Comment: @pskink i tried ViewDragHelper but it doesn't allow view to be independent from edge i.e view should be attached to either one of the edge then it allows drag and fling.

Comment: `"independent from edge"` i have no idea what you mean

Comment: meaning view doesn't take up full width touching edges or view is not on top or at bottom touching edges.

Comment: with `ViewDragHelper` your `View` can have any size and can be placed anywhere

Comment: what i found out was ViewDragHelper is the underlying api of navigation drawer which involves edge sliding or dragging a view on edge.

Comment: @pskink I'll have a look at it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106579/discussion-between-vinkrish-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `View.OnTouchListener` on the  `View` to drag it.

Pass the motion events to a `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`.
You need to override `onFling()`, which will inform you about flinging.